# Postfix: delivering "local" mail to GMail, but sending other mail

Tags: postfix, smtp

I need to set up a server to send messages to a few different people automatically. The recipients are at two different domains, let's say mydomain.com and otherdomain.com. The messages need to come from a email address at mydomain.com. mydomain.com is a Google Apps for Enterprise domain.

I have configured Postfix to say that it is mydomain.com (myhostname = mydomain.com and mydomain = mydomain.com). It currently sends messages to otherdomain.com just fine. However, when sending mail to mydomain.com, I don't want it to deliver locally, but rather to GMail's server, so that the mail actually gets to the recipient. When delivering today, postfix tries to deliver it locally and gets an error "User unknown in local recipient table"

I tried setting transport_maps with the following entry:

localdomain smtp:aspmx.l.google.com

Hoping that that would redirect local messages over to Google's SMTP server, but that did not work.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to consider

- ensure `mydestination` parameter doesn't contain mydomain.com, mydomain or myhostname
- Set `relay_domains = mydomain.com`  in main.cf